# Solving by Masters theorem and recursion tree gives different answers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence, master-theorem

Suppose we have been given a recurrence relation **T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n**. And need to find the time complexity.
My problem is why I am getting different answers by master theorem and using recursion tree method.

**By Master Theorem for equation T(n) = aT(n/b) + O(n<sup>k</sup>log<sup>p</sup>n)**

Here a=2,b=3,p=0,k=1 and as a < b<sup>k</sup> here i.e 2 < 3<sup>1</sup> by masters theorem it gives us T(n) = O(n) time complexity.

**Here is my recursion tree method**

[image]

And at the end I seriously don't know what did I found out. It looks something like O(n.2<sup>logn</sup>).

1. Surely its not the answer and I have messed it up. But I don't get where I am wrong? What is right approach?
2. Also I wanted to ask if recurrence relations **T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n** and **T(n) = 2T(n/3) + C** are both same? where C is a constant in 2nd equation.

Comment: (1 - (2/3)^(log n)) is Theta(1) because (2/3)^(log n) goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ohhh! My bad. But thats a relief, it means my concept of solving was correct. But will u please answer my 2nd question ?

Comment: Try the Master Theorem again.

Comment: If u r saying me to apply master theorem on my 2nd question's 2nd equation then yes it gives a different answer and that shows that equation T(n) = 2T(n/3) + C & T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n are different but my doubt is I found one equation T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + n, here in solution they treated n as constant C, that's why I asked that 2nd question.

Comment: Wait, I will post a different question for that doubt

Comment: For T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + n you can write U(k) = T(exp k), hence T(n) = U(log n), then derive the U recurrence: U(k) = T(exp k) = T((exp k)^(1/2)) + exp k = U(log (exp k)^(1/2)) + exp k = U(k/2) + exp k. This recurrence is solvable with the Master Theorem: U(k) = Theta(exp k). Then translate back to T(n) = U(log n) = Theta(exp log n) = Theta(n).